# Check if the string contains at least two alphabets and check if it's contains other than alphabets

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, reverse

Java Program to get a string from the user. If the string size is even, then reverse the second part of the string and display that string. If the string size is odd, then reverse the string from the middle character and display it. The String should have only alphabets. Else, display " is not a valid string". The string should have at least two alphabets, else display "Size of string  is too low".

```
package Section6;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Challenge6 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the string: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
    
        if (str.length() == 0 || str.length() <= 1) {
            System.out.print("Size of string " + str + " is too low");
            return;
        }
        else if (str.length() == 2 && str.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$"))
        {
            if(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$", str))
            {
                 Reverse_string(str);
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.print(str + " is not a valid string");
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (str.length() > 2)
        {
            if(str != null && str.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
                Reverse(str);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Reverse_string(String s) {
        String reverse = ""; 
        int length = s.length();

        for (int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
              reverse = reverse + s.charAt(i);

        System.out.println(reverse);
    }

    public static void Reverse(String str) {
        int mid = str.length() / 2;
        String[] parts = { str.substring(0, mid), str.substring(mid) };
        String p2 = parts[0]; // first part
        String p1 = parts[1]; // second part

        String s1a = str.substring(0, (str.length() / 2));
        String s1b = str.substring((str.length() / 2));
        System.out.print(p2);
        int i = s1b.length();
        while (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(s1b.charAt(i - 1));
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a problem description and your code. So what is it that you're struggling with? What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to edit a little  and got the desired output.

As my question says, i just had to check for string length is 2 but i should not be reversing it. so removed the reverse method from this condition.

And for non-alphabet character check. i ham checking it but just have to add a print statement to displaying saying that its an invalid string.